# Collect Bluetooth Low Energy Data

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I like to analyze bluetooth low energy advertising packages on an Arduino Uno. This tasks poses me problem because the BLE modules I have found only work in device mode (Adafruit, RedBearLab, and other nRF51822 and nRF8001 based) and can't collect data. Does anyone know about such projects or have experiences with this?

Comment: NRF51 devices do support central role. Just use the correct softdevice (S120/S130).

Comment: Are there tutorials for reprogramming? I have a JLink and a nRF51 but I'm unsure about the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit has the Bluefruit Sniffer requires a host PC instead of an arduino UNO (http://www.adafruit.com/product/2269) it basically has a nrf51822 module which talks to the PC over a UART using the FTDI usb to Serial converter chip. I suspect that you could probably get a similar nrf51822 module and flash the sniffer firmware( found here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_Firmware/tree/master/sniffer/1.0.1)use the Jlink to flash the firmware onto the BLE module and use that to communicate with the arduino UNO over a uart connection. Hope that helps, Good luck!

you can try using one of these modules maybe:

http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/MDBT40P%C2%A0%C2%A0nRF51822%C2%A0based%C2%A0BLE%C2%A0module-p-2503.html

https://www.adafruit.com/products/2479